# Return the next nth result \w+ after a hyphen globally

Tags: python, regex, regex-lookarounds

Just getting to the next stage of understanding regex, hoping the community can help...

string = `These.Final.Hours-AUSVERSION.2013-TEST-TESTAGAIN-YIFY.cp(tt123456).MiLLENiUM.mp4`

There are multiple test names preceded by a '-' hyphen which I derive from regex 
`\(?<=-)\w+\g`

Result:

- AUSVERSION
- TEST
- TESTAGAIN
- YIFY

I can parse the very last result using greediness with regex `\(?!.*-)(?<=-)\w+\g`

Result:

- YIFI (4th & last result)

Can you please help me parse either the 1st, 2nd, or 3rd result Globally using the same string?

Comment: Do you mean [`/(?<=-|-\s)\w+/g`](https://regex101.com/r/wR3mB5/1)? Or something like  [`/(?<=-)\w+/`](https://regex101.com/r/wR3mB5/2), etc.? *either the 1st, 2nd, or 3rd result Globally* does not sound clear.

Comment: https://regex101.com/#python

Comment: So, just use `-\s*(\w+)` with `re.findall` and access the matches using the necessary index. **See [this demo](https://ideone.com/h0LykP).**

Comment: Thank you people. If we just go back to basics, is there anyway to represent the 2nd or 3rd result itself in regex i.e. result {2} or result {3} in a result list of 4 choices?

Comment: Yes, but it is rarely what you need. `^(?:.*?-\s*(\w+)){4}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Python, you can get these matches with a simple `-\s*(\w+)` regex and `re.findall` and then access any match with the appropriate index:

See [IDEONE demo](https://ideone.com/h0LykP):

```
import re
s = 'These.Final.Hours-AUSVERSION.2013-TEST-TESTAGAIN-YIFY.cp(tt123456).MiLLENiUM.mp4'
r = re.findall(r'-\s*(\w+)', s)
print(r[0]) # => AUSVERSION
print(r[1]) # => TEST
print(r[2]) # => TESTAGAIN
print(r[3]) # => YIFY
```

The `-\s*(\w+)` pattern search for a hyphen, followed with 0+ whitespaces, and then captures 1+ digits, letters or underscores. `re.findall` only returns the texts captured with capturing groups, so you only get those Group 1 values captured with `(\w+)`.

To get these matches one by one, with `re.search`, you can use `^(?:.*?-\s*(\w+)){n}`, where *n* is the match index you want. Here is a [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/hY9aN7/1).

A [quick Python demo](https://ideone.com/1mjWYS) (in real code, assign the result of `re.search` and only access Group 1 value after checking if there was a match):

```
s = "These.Final.Hours-AUSVERSION.2013-TEST-TESTAGAIN- YIFY.cp(tt123456).MiLLENiUM.mp4"
print(re.search(r'^(?:.*?-\s*(\w+))', s).group(1))
print(re.search(r'^(?:.*?-\s*(\w+)){2}', s).group(1))
print(re.search(r'^(?:.*?-\s*(\w+)){3}', s).group(1))
print(re.search(r'^(?:.*?-\s*(\w+)){4}', s).group(1))
```

**Explanation of the pattern**:

- `^` - start of string
- `(?:.*?-\s*(\w+)){2}` - a non-capturing group that matches (here) 2 sequences of:

  - `.*?` - 0+ any characters other than a newline (since no `re.DOTALL` modifier is used) up to the first...
  - `-` - hyphen
  - `\s*` - 0 or more whitespaces
  - `(\w+)` - Group 1 capturing 1+ word characters (letters, digits or underscores).