# Return specific matched value in a regex query

Tags: regex

I have a string that looks like this:

```
5 Secs ( 14.2725% ) 60 Secs ( 12.630% ) 300 Secs ( 15.5993% )
```

Using `(\d{2}[.]\d{3})`, I can match the values I want; but, I just need value 1 on one query, value 2 on another query and value 3 for the third.  This is part of a monitoring system, so it has to be done with a single line of regex, I don't have access to other shell tools that would make this easy.

Comment: What are you actually trying to extract from the example you gave?  By the way, I think you are going to need to escape a bunch of stuff in the regex you mentioned.

Comment: There's virtually no information about what programming language or shell you have. Also, if you do have a shell, why do you say "I don't have access to other shell tools"? There's a ton of shell tools usually installed on a system. Maybe you could fill in the details for us?

Comment: An almost identical question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37924545/return-the-next-nth-result-w-after-a-hyphen-globally/37924922#37924922

Answer (score 0):

## Description

```regex
^(?:[^(]*\([^)]*\)){2}[^(]*\(\s*\K[0-9]{2}[.][0-9]{3}
                   ^^^
```

[image: Regular expression visualization]

The number in the `{2}` can be changed on demand and the expression will then select the N+1 percent value in the string. If you select `0` then the expression will match the first percent, if you select `1` then the expression will match the second percent... and so on.

This expression assumes the language supports the `\K` regex command that forces the engine to drop everything that it has matched uptil the `\K`.

## Example

**Live Demo**

https://regex101.com/r/oX0mJ4/1

**Sample text**

```
5 Secs ( 14.2725% ) 60 Secs ( 12.630% ) 300 Secs ( 15.5993% )
```

**Sample Matches**

Using the expression as written it returns the 3 third entry.

```
15.599
```

## Explanation

```
NODE                     EXPLANATION
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  ^                        the beginning of a "line"
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  (?:                      group, but do not capture (2 times):
----------------------------------------------------------------------
    [^(]*                    any character except: '(' (0 or more
                             times (matching the most amount
                             possible))
----------------------------------------------------------------------
    \(                       '('
----------------------------------------------------------------------
    [^)]*                    any character except: ')' (0 or more
                             times (matching the most amount
                             possible))
----------------------------------------------------------------------
    \)                       ')'
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  ){2}                     end of grouping
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  [^(]*                    any character except: '(' (0 or more times
                           (matching the most amount possible))
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  \(                       '('
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  \s*                      whitespace (\n, \r, \t, \f, and " ") (0 or
                           more times (matching the most amount
                           possible))
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  \K                       'K'
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  [0-9]{2}                 any character of: '0' to '9' (2 times)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  [.]                      any character of: '.'
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  [0-9]{3}                 any character of: '0' to '9' (3 times)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
```